# how to make retrieve button for previous Value

Tags: ios, swift

can someone help me

i make button to retrieve previous Values

but i have two TextFiled

i must write in two TextFiled for work retrieve button

i do not want this happens

i want when I write in the first TextFiled, retrieve button work without any problem

but if i write in first TextFiled and second TextFiled at the same time i want retrieve button work without any problem

```
    var previousValues: [String] = [String]();
    var previousValues1: [String] = [String]();


    previousValues.append(TextFailde.text ?? "error");
    previousValues1.append(TextFilde1.text ?? "error");

    if self.previousValues.count > 0  {
            let previousValue = self.previousValues.removeLast()
            let subtracted = (Int(self.lblZeroUs.text!)!) - (Int(previousValue)!)
            self.lblZeroUs.text = "\(subtracted)"
        }

    else if self.previousValues1.count > 0  {
            let previousValue = self.previousValues1.removeLast()
            let subtracted2 = (Int(self.lblZeroThey.text!)!) - (Int(previousValue)!)
            self.lblZeroThey.text = "\(subtracted2)"
        }
```

[image]

and here the error

[image]

Comment: not clear.  what is your retrieve button code  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
previousValues.append(TextFailde.text ?? "error");
previousValues.append(TextFilde1.text ?? "error");
```

You added to the same array twice, try changing the code to

```
previousValues.append(TextFailde.text ?? "error");
previousValues1.append(TextFilde1.text ?? "error");
```

Comment: doesn't work , when i write in first TextFiled and click Button (do it) and after that when i click (retreat) Button i got error because i don't write in the second TextFiled

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors, first of all you dont declare your properties with the first letter in uppercase, it's considered a bad practice.

Then, when you involve your properties in mathematical operations what do you need is to assign them a start value, especially if your code try to convert strings.

In Swift, you don’t need to write semicolons at the end of every statement.

I dont know the rest of your code, but your lines crash because you attempt to run mathematical operations using properties have nil as value.

This below it's just an example to avoid the first crashing for nil:

```
textFailde.text = "0"
textFilde1.text = "0"
previousValues.append(textFailde.text ?? String(0))
previousValues1.append(textFilde1.text ?? String(0))
self.lblZeroUs.text = String(0)
self.lblZeroThey.text = String(0)

if self.previousValues.count > 0  {
   let subtracted = (Int(self.lblZeroUs.text!)!) - (Int(self.previousValues.last!))!
   self.previousValues.removeLast()
   self.lblZeroUs.text = "\(subtracted)"
}
else if self.previousValues1.count > 0  {
   let subtracted2 = (Int(self.lblZeroThey.text!)!) - (Int(self.previousValues1.last!))!
   self.previousValues1.removeLast()
   self.lblZeroThey.text = "\(subtracted2)"
}
```

Comment: thx , but still doesn't work if i don't write in first textfiled i got error

Comment: Check on your code if you clean your textfield after pressing button ;) remember that your code depend upon textfields values, they cant be cleaned without a starting value like 0. I've launch this answer in my compiler without errors

Comment: it's work i change textfiled.text?.removeAll to textfiled.text = "0" < after i click to button (do it) , it's good but every time when i want to write number in textfiled i must delete the number (0) , man my English it's not good if you don't understand tell me , and thank you for trying to help me

Comment: You can insert a var to textFieldShouldReturn(_:) everytime your textfield is inserted var textfieldValue = textfield.text, and the init value if textfield is empty for this var can be 0, it's just an idea, and then you can have an empty textfield (because you handle textFieldValue)